# C# Elvis Operator - will the parameters be evaluated?

Tags: c#, operators

Quick question
Will someOtherDelegate be evaluated even if SomeObject.SomeDelegateProperty is null and invokation won't occur? I assume no since the point of (?.) is to stop execution if null but I need confirmation.

```
SomeObject.SomeDelegateProperty?.Invoke(someOtherDelegate());
```

Thank you

Comment: It will stop execution when `SomeObject.SomeDelegateProperty == null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Her my test example:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var SomeObject = new FakeClass();
        SomeObject.SomeDelegateProperty?.Invoke( someOtherDelegate() );
    }

    public static string someOtherDelegate()
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    public class FakeClass
    {
        public Action<string> SomeDelegateProperty;
    }
}
```

And IL code:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    // Размер кода:       31 (0x1f)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init ([0] class StackOverflow.Examples.Program/FakeClass SomeObject)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void 
    StackOverflow.Examples.Program/FakeClass::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldfld      class [mscorlib]System.Action`1<string> 
    StackOverflow.Examples.Program/FakeClass::SomeDelegateProperty
    IL_000d:  dup
    IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0013
    IL_0010:  pop
    IL_0011:  br.s       IL_001e
    IL_0013:  call       string      StackOverflow.Examples.Program::someOtherDelegate()
    IL_0018:  callvirt   instance void class 
    [mscorlib]System.Action`1<string>::Invoke(!0)
    IL_001d:  nop
    IL_001e:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

How you can see instructions `IL_000e:  brtrue.s   IL_0013` check `SomeDelegateProperty` and if it not null call `someOtherDelegate` on address `IL_0013` otherwise goto to the end address `IL_001e`.

Comment: although I answered, your answer is much more refined with proof/explanation so I'm marking it as answer - thank you for the research

Answer (score 0):

It will stop execution when SomeObject.SomeDelegateProperty == null.
As Jeroen van Langen commented